# Flutter web firebase authentication issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

i am facing an issue in firebase authentication in flutter web, below i am pasting the web's index file code...

```
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

in my pubspec.yaml file i have firebase dependencies

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  firebase: ^7.3.0
```

whole authentication code works in mobile Android/Ios but not in web and i can't see any logs the only log appears when clicking the login button second time, first time nothing happens -_- thats the main issue, any one please help me resolve my issue thanks.

> Overflow on channel: plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth.  Messages on this channel are being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInWithCredential on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

my signin code

```
    AuthResult authResult = await EmailPassAuthentication.loginWithEmail(
      // invoked on error
      () {
        if (kIsWeb) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Invalid Login Details'),
                content: Text('Incorrect email or password !'),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          showSnackBar('Incorrect email or password !', false);
        }
      },
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
    );
    if (authResult != null && authResult.user != null) {
      // user logged in success.
      user = await FirestoreHelper.getUserFromData(authResult.user);
//      showSnackBar('Successfuly Logged in', true);
      _navigate();
    }
```

and the static loginWithEmail method where i handle signin

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    AuthResult authResult = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).catchError(
      (error) {
        onErrorCallback.call();
      },
    );
    return authResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using old versions of firebase, the best thing to do is to update all the dependencies. Therefore open the terminal and execute:

```
flutter pub outdated
```

The above will identify out-of-date package dependencies and get advice on how to update them, use the outdated command. For details, see the Dart pub outdated documentation.

Then execute:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

which will upgrade the packages.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#upgrading-packages

Comment: okay thanks for guiding... i'll try this and one more thing i am using master channel should  switch to stable ? or its okay with master channel ?

Comment: flutter web is still in beta.. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#create-a-new-project-with-web-support